# Reload callback not working

Tags: angularjs

The list is not updating when I trigger reload callback function after modal close.

```
 // Inside my view
 <div tasty-table
             bind-resource-callback="showStudents.loadAllStudentsRecords"
             bind-init="showStudents.init"
             bind-reload="reloadCallback"

// Inside my controller
...
Other implementations here
...
vm.reloadCallback = function () { alert("Called"); };

vm.delete = function (studId) {

        // Show modal
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'AppScripts/Views/Student/DeleteStudent.html',
            controller: 'DeleteStudentCtrl as deleteStudent',
            backdrop  : 'static',
            keyboard  : false,
            resolve: {
                studentId: function () {
                    return studId;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (status) {
            if (status === 'ok')
            {
                vm.reloadCallback();
            }
        });
```

The alert was executed when i call the reloadCallback function but the list is not updated
By the way im using "controller as" syntax.

Comment: Is there anything you have tried?

Comment: @Sherlock Did you get any solution to this issue ? I am getting the same issue and unable to find a solution.

Comment: @UmakantaBehera nope. I changed implementation to redirect my process to another page

Answer (score 1):

Because of incomplete code i'm not able to understand which method you are using to close the modal window. Check working Plunkr here. Hope it will solve your problem. https://plnkr.co/edit/LnV021AjBXhamG8ygLp1?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.studentId = "123"
    $scope.reloadCallback = function(){
        alert("Call back")
    }
   $scope.showModal = function(){
      var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
           templateUrl: 'deletestudent.html',
           controller: 'DeleteStudentCtrl as deleteStudent',
           backdrop  : 'static',
           keyboard  : false,
           resolve: {
               studentId: function () {
                   return $scope.studentId;
               }
           }
       });
       modalInstance.result.then(function (status) {
           if (status === 'ok'){
               $scope.reloadCallback();
           }
       });
    }
});

app.controller('DeleteStudentCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance,    studentId) {
     console.log(studentId);
     $scope.closeMe = function(){
          $uibModalInstance.close('ok');
    }
})
```

Documentation for modal https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs

Comment: thanks for the respond, reloadCallback is an API for `ng-tasty` directive in angular, what you answered is not related with the issue